Exporting bitmap files with a known color change
I know that to export a raster with a given color, you need to export it. You need to specify the parameters in the "Data Export" section in the Output raster section: Color. model and RGB. But how can this export be done for multiple rasters at the same time?
I have compiled a script for batch execution, but it does not perform what I expected.
import arcpy
import os

output_folder = 'F:/mol_2_N02/1/img'
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
    if lyr.isRasterLayer:
        raster_path = lyr.dataSource
        
        if raster_path.lower().endswith('.tif'):
            raster_name = os.path.basename(raster_path)
            new_raster_name = raster_name.replace('.tif', '_copia.tif')
            new_raster_path = os.path.join(output_folder, new_raster_name)
        
            arcpy.CopyRaster_management(lyr, new_raster_path, '', '', '', 'NONE', 'NONE', '')

print("Finish.")

1 photo - what do I set in the Data Export so that the output raster is with the specified color

2 photo - which rasters do I need to export

3 photo - what I get after running the script

I'm trying to batch export rasters with their color scheme, which they currently have. Such rasters were obtained when executed with the "Kriging" tool.

I'm not understanding what you're trying to do, is the raster to have a single constant value or is it that you wish to apply the symbology (stretch) to a group of rasters? The images you've put in your question aren't working.

I see, you're trying to export using a renderer. There's no chance of doing this in python https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140196/automate-exporting-of-rasters-using-renderer-in-arcgis , you'd need to use C#, C++ or VB.net to leverage the ArcObjects API. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177580/exporting-a-raster-with-renderer-enabled-to-file has a bit of code. Perhaps the closest you could get is to use export map to a GeoTIFF file. Consider making a mosaic dataset from all your rasters, symbolize it once, export it once and then cut it up if you need smaller tiles.
